# Connect not logging errors from Callback URLs after API-created envelopes are completed

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending signature requests via the DocuSign API and passing through a callback URL for Connect to send the document back via once the envelope is completed. My api request is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <emailSubject>Signature Request on Document</emailSubject>
  <status>sent</status>
  <documents>
    <document>
      <documentId>1</documentId>
      <name>Repo Document</name>
      <fileExtension>.pdf</fileExtension>
    </document>
  </documents>
  <recipients>
    <signers>
      <signer>
        <recipientId>1</recipientId>
        <email>dsuser@email.com</email>
        <name>dsuser</name>
        <tabs>
          <signHereTabs>
            <signHere>
              <xPosition>165</xPosition>
              <yPosition>10</yPosition>
              <scaleValue>1</scaleValue>
              <documentId>1</documentId>
              <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
            </signHere>
          </signHereTabs>
        </tabs>
      </signer>
    </signers>
  </recipients>
  <eventNotification>
    <EnvelopeEvents>
      <envelopeEvent>
        <envelopeEventStatusCode>completed</envelopeEventStatusCode>
      </envelopeEvent>
    </EnvelopeEvents>
    <includeDocuments>true</includeDocuments>
    <loggingEnabled>true</loggingEnabled>
    <requireAcknowledgement>true</requireAcknowledgement>
    <url>https://docusign.myconnectlistenerurl.com:443/docusignconnect/doc/2/2/29/completed/sign/user/3833d4cb83d2b92a7147381d32135df48ec5fc759216f32817597df305885245</url>
  </eventNotification>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

The envelope gets created correctly, the user is notified, signs the document and completed the process perfectly. But as of last week, connect never sends the document back to the callback url specified above.

I have troubleshot issues like this before by parsing the connect logs for http errors, but NONE of the documents i send show up in the connect logs anymore, in the new experience. First thing i checked was that `requireAcknowledgement` was set to true, which it is and always has been (i wrote this integration in 2014 and it has worked until now with this server.) I don't see successes or failures or anything, both log screens in admin->connect are blank.

[I also followed this new guide for manually publishing envelope(s) via connect](https://support.docusign.com/articles/How-to-Perform-a-Manual-Publish-of-Connect-Data-in-Low-or-High-Volumes), to see if it worked and if it would produce a log-- the result of these actions all say success but i still see no logs of any kind.

**6/19 edit:**
I have found a bug in my code that i was able to patch, but this error as it occured should have been returning a 500 to DS connect. I used to be able to see these errors but they appear to no longer displaying anywhere in the Connect log interface in the new experience.

So the issue remaining is that Connect using a callback URL does not display returned errors in the Connect logs after POSTing an API-created envelope. I have updated the question title as such.

Comment: It used to work, right? Does your server support TLS 1.1 or (better TLS 1.2)?

Comment: @LarryK yes, my server supports 1.1 and 1.2

Comment: If there hasn't been a code change on your side, you'll probably want to open a case with DocuSign Support.

Comment: @drew is so no longer the place for developer support? i thought their support portal was for customers

Comment: There was a few changes/updates on limiting allowed requests: check this and double check if your listener is not blocked because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50819039/5405209

Comment: @Payf1 i am using https in production as i always have, and the server supports TLS 1.2